# Blue text on blue background for usercard has insufficient contrast

Tags: bug, design, accessibility, user-card

The colors in light mode have a [contrast ratio of 3.22:1](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=4E82C2&bcolor=D9EAF7):

[image: light mode user card]

And in dark mode, they have a [contrast ratio of 3.59:1](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=33A7FF&bcolor=1B4A6F):

[image: dark mode user card]

Both are normal text (smaller than 18pt and not bold), which [W3C accessibility guidelines](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#contrast-minimum) advise should have a contrast ratio of at least 4.5:1.

Comment: Same report on MSO: [Please fix the user card colors in dark mode; they fail contast tests](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411121/4642212).

Comment: My current workaround to this is to use the [High contrast mode beta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411820). I was straining to read the text otherwise and for a bit had a custom style set but the high contrast mode works better for more things. That doesn't mean that it shouldn't be fixed in regular dark mode, though.